# Display answers in random order for multiple choice quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with having the answers appear in random order for this multiple choice quiz. Currently, the questions are chosen in random order but the answers are always in the same spot. I tried to follow the same logic of what randomized the questions from an object but when I apply it to the answers it doesn't work.

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const resultsButton = document.getElementById('results-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
let answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
let imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
let resultsElement = document.getElementById('results');
let text = document.getElementById('text');
const bannerElement = document.getElementById('banner');
const titleElement = document.getElementById('title');

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex, shuffledAnswers;
let score;

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
restartButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++;
  setNextQuestion();
  text.classList.add('hide');

})

resultsButton.addEventListener('click', showResults)


function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  setNextQuestion();
  resultsElement.classList.add('hide');
  restartButton.classList.add('hide')
  score = 0;
  text.classList.add('hide');
  answerButtonsElement.classList.remove('hide');
  imageElement.classList.remove('hide');
  bannerElement.classList.add('hide');
  titleElement.classList.add('hide');
  questionElement.classList.remove('hide')
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]);
}

function showQuestion(question) {
    imageElement.src = question.img;
   questionElement.innerText = question.question;
   question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'choice');
    button.innerText = answer.text;
    button.classList.add('col-6');
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct;
      
    } 
    button.addEventListener('mousedown', selectAnswer);
    button.addEventListener('mouseup', disableButtons);
    
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
  
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body);
  nextButton.classList.add('hide');
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target;
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
  text.classList.remove('hide');
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct);
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
 resultsButton.classList.remove('hide') 
  }
 if (correct) {
        score += 33.3;
        text.innerHTML = 'That is correct!';
        selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        
 } else {
        text.innerHTML = 'That is incorrect.';
        selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        
    }

}

function disableButtons() {
  answerButtonsElement.disabled = true;
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  /*if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }*/
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}


function showResults() {
    questionContainerElement.classList.add('hide');
    resultsElement.classList.remove('hide');
    resultsElement.innerHTML = `Your final score was ${score}%!`;
    resultsButton.classList.add('hide');
    restartButton.classList.remove('hide');
    questionElement.classList.add('hide');
    answerButtonsElement.classList.add('hide');
    text.classList.add('hide');
}


const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '5', correct: false },
      { text: '9', correct: false },
   { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '3', correct: false }

    ],
  img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/2plus2_logo.jpg'
  }, 
  {
    question: 'How many planets are in our solar system?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: false },
      { text: '5', correct: false },
      { text: '9', correct: true }
    ],
  img: 'https://static.techspot.com/images2/news/bigimage/2019/11/2019-11-21-image-6.png'
  },
  {
    question: "How many seconds are in an hour?",
    answers: [
      { text: '60', correct: true },
      { text: '30', correct: false },
      { text: '90', correct: false },
      { text: '24', correct: false }
    ],
  img: 'https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/27923419/thumb/7.jpg'
  }
]
```

```css
.container .card {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

.answer-buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col-6 {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  outline: none; 
  margin: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 90px; 
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.btn.correct {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.btn.wrong {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;  
}

.start-btn, .next-btn, .results-btn, .restart-btn {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}

.controls {
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#image {
    max-width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 6%;
    min-width: 350px;
}

#question {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 2% auto -2% auto;
}

.col {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.results {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3% auto;
}

#restart-btn {
    margin: 2% auto;
}

#banner {
  margin: 2% auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}

#results-btn, #next-btn {
  
}

#title {
  font-size: 200%;
}

#footer {
  color: rgb(237, 29, 36);
}
```

```html
  <div class="container card text-center mx-auto">
    
    <div id="question-container" class="row hide">
      <div id="question" class="col">Question</div>
    </div>
    <div id="image-container" class="row text-center">
  <img id ="image" class="text-center image hide"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <p id="text" class="col text text-center"></p> 
    </div>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="row answer-buttons hide mx-2 mt-1"></div>
    <div id="results" class="results hide row">
        <p class="col">Congratulations!</p>   
    </div>
    <div class="controls row d-flex">
        <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn col col-2 mb-5">Start</button>
        <button id="restart-btn" class="restart-btn btn hide col col-2" onclick="restartQuiz()">Restart Quiz</button>
        <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide col col-2 my-2">Next</button>
        <button id="results-btn" class="results-btn btn hide col col-2 my-2">Get Results!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Al_byte/szb5d1h6/

Comment: Please post the complete code with html. And better would be that you can create a runnable snippet. [How to create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Sounds like you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: I've edited the post to include a JSFiddle

Comment: That's nice. It's a lot easier getting help if you create a running snippet.

Comment: Alright, updated again with code snippet. Sorry, first time posting a question here lol.

Answer (score 0):

You are not disabling the buttons, you are disabling the div that contains the buttons.

Following the idea of the code, you could check if the div is disabled and block the function that selects the elements.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/toh0v6w9/1/

I have removed the disableButtons function on the mouseButton up event, set the disabled attr in the selectAnswer and resetted the disabled attr in the resetState

```
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const resultsButton = document.getElementById('results-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
let answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
let imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
let resultsElement = document.getElementById('results');
let text = document.getElementById('text');
const bannerElement = document.getElementById('banner');
const titleElement = document.getElementById('title');

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex, shuffledAnswers;
let score;

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
restartButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++;
  setNextQuestion();
  text.classList.add('hide');

})

resultsButton.addEventListener('click', showResults)


function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  setNextQuestion();
  resultsElement.classList.add('hide');
  restartButton.classList.add('hide')
  score = 0;
  text.classList.add('hide');
  answerButtonsElement.classList.remove('hide');
  imageElement.classList.remove('hide');
  bannerElement.classList.add('hide');
  titleElement.classList.add('hide');
  questionElement.classList.remove('hide')
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]);
}

function showQuestion(question) {
    imageElement.src = question.img;
      questionElement.innerText = question.question;
      question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'choice');
    button.innerText = answer.text;
    button.classList.add('col-6');
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct;

    } 
    button.addEventListener('mousedown', selectAnswer);

    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })

}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body);
  nextButton.classList.add('hide');
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
  answerButtonsElement.disabled = false;
}



function selectAnswer(e) {
    if(!answerButtonsElement.disabled){
  const selectedButton = e.target;
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
  text.classList.remove('hide');
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct);
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    resultsButton.classList.remove('hide')  
  }
    if (correct) {
        score += 33.3;
        text.innerHTML = 'That is correct!';
        selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

    } else {
        text.innerHTML = 'That is incorrect.';
        selectedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    }
    answerButtonsElement.disabled = true;
    }

}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  /*if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }*/
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}


function showResults() {
    questionContainerElement.classList.add('hide');
    resultsElement.classList.remove('hide');
    resultsElement.innerHTML = `Your final score was ${score}%!`;
    resultsButton.classList.add('hide');
    restartButton.classList.remove('hide');
    questionElement.classList.add('hide');
    answerButtonsElement.classList.add('hide');
    text.classList.add('hide');
}


const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '5', correct: false },
      { text: '9', correct: false },
            { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '3', correct: false }

    ],
        img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/2plus2_logo.jpg'
  }, 
  {
    question: 'How many planets are in our solar system?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: false },
      { text: '5', correct: false },
      { text: '9', correct: true }
    ],
        img: 'https://static.techspot.com/images2/news/bigimage/2019/11/2019-11-21-image-6.png'
  },
  {
    question: "How many seconds are in an hour?",
    answers: [
      { text: '60', correct: true },
      { text: '30', correct: false },
      { text: '90', correct: false },
      { text: '24', correct: false }
    ],
        img: 'https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/27923419/thumb/7.jpg'
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish, I really appreciate the help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve it by accessing the parent div with ID & accessing  all the child elements using `querySelectorAll()` , then disabling all the buttons the style with `pointer-events: none;'.This property defines whether or not an element reacts to pointer events.

I have added the code in `function selectAnswer(e)`

```
let getElem = document.getElementById("answer-buttons").querySelectorAll(".choice");
   for (let i = 0; i < getElem.length; i++) {
      getElem[i].style.pointerEvents = "none";
   }
```

There is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/yhf5sx2u/13/

Let me know if this help you

Comment: Thank you! This solution works exactly as I intended.

Comment: Glad to help :)